# How to disable manifest mode in vcpkg?

Tags: c++, vcpkg

Vcpkg has a manifest mode where one specifies a vcpkg.json file with all the packages required for a project. I would like to temporarily disable this feature and instead use `vcpkg install mypackage` directly. However, if a vcpkg.json file is present in your root directory vcpkg automatically switches to manifest mode, so when I try to run `vcpkg install` I get:

> error: In manifest mode, `vcpkg install` does not support individual package arguments.
> To install additional packages, edit vcpkg.json and then run `vcpkg install` without any package arguments.

To get around this I instead tried this:

```
export VCPKG_MANIFEST_MODE=OFF
./vcpkg install mypackage
```

But I still get the same error. Is there a way to disable manifest mode? The only way I've found so far is to delete the vcpkg.json file temporarily, but this is rather cumbersome.

Comment: Just install the library from another folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of vcpkg installed (such as one with Visual Studio, another one as 'stand alone'), you may not be using the install base you think you are using.

From this thread: [vcpkg/issues/32641](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/32641)

> vcpkg.exe will be searched via the environment variable PATH. This may
> or may not be the same as running .\vcpkg.exe, the executable in the
> current working directory...

Additional helpful comments later on:

> This most likely caused by your prompt getting confused between a copy
> of vcpkg coming from Visual Studio (which does not support classic
> mode) and a separate copy of vcpkg you've installed yourself. To
> confirm this, run where.exe vcpkg:
>
> > where.exe vcpkg C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe
>
> and check the value of VCPKG_ROOT:
>
> > echo %VCPKG_ROOT% C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\vcpkg
>
> You can fix this in a few ways:
>
> Use Manifest Mode instead of Classic Mode. Set VCPKG_ROOT to the vcpkg
> instance you want to use. This will be cleared when you close your
> command prompt. Unset VCPKG_ROOT and invoke vcpkg with a specific path
> instead of vcpkg. Uninstall the vcpkg optional package from your
> Visual Studio instance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error **This vcpkg distribution does not have a classic mode instance** trying to run `vcpkg install somelibrary:sometriplet`.  By prefacing the command with `.\` I was able to proceed, i.e. `.\vcpkg install somelibrary:sometriplet`.

This answer does not address the following aspect of the OP:

> if a vcpkg.json file is present in your root directory vcpkg
> automatically switches to manifest mode

But this answer *may* disable manifest mode in the event you're running from a **vcpkg** root directory that acts like it is in manifest mode for no apparent reason, i.e. no `vcpkg.json` file present in the root.